# Error downloading Pterodactyl with the command "composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader"

Tags: php, installation, panel

I encounter a problem during the download of the Pterodactyl Panel: when I launch the Error downloading Pterodactyl command with the command `composer compose --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`
I have an error which is:

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for s1lentium/iptools v1.1.1 -> satisfiable by s1lentium/iptools[v1.1.1].
    - s1lentium/iptools v1.1.1 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I checked and I have everything when I run php --ini:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
```

And I didn't find the installation of s1lentium / iptools v1.1.1.
I have been looking for quite a while but cannot find any thanks for any help.

Comment: "the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system" so install that extension.

Comment: Thx that function, happy new year.

Answer (score 0):

`apt install php7.4-bcmath` to the rescue!

Comment: Thx that function, happy new year.